# How to avoid numbers from changing cell size each time program is run?

Tags: javascript, css, html

How to avoid numbers from changing cell size each time program is run?
I would like to have equal spacing in-between numbers without cells shifting left to right.

```
var arr = new Array(5);

var i = 0, j, n;

var OK = true;

var printThis = " "; 

var table = "<table style = font-size:25px; >"; 

while (i < arr.length) {

      n = Math.floor((Math.random() * 35) + 1);

      for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {

          if (arr[j] == n) {
            OK = false;
          }
      }

      if (OK) {
          arr[i] = n;

          table += "<td>" + arr[i] + "</td>"; 

          i++;
      }
      OK = true;

}

table += "</table>";

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = table;
```

Answer (score 0):

Give a static width to `td`

```js
var arr = new Array(5);

var i = 0,
  j, n;

var OK = true;

var printThis = " ";

var table = "<table style = 'font-size:25px;'>";

while (i < arr.length) {

  n = Math.floor((Math.random() * 35) + 1);

  for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {

    if (arr[j] == n) {
      OK = false;
    }
  }

  if (OK) {
    arr[i] = n;

    table += "<td width='25px'>" + arr[i] + "</td>";

    i++;
  }
  OK = true;

}

table += "</table>";

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = table;
```

```html
<div style='border:1px solid black;display:inline-block' id='demo'></div>
```

Comment: Setting static width to td did help but still the numbers are slightly shifting but not as much as before.

Comment: want same spacing between numbers?

Comment: Maybe it will help with spacing, I am not sure how to write the code,  but it seems like the numbers are pushing the columns each time  I generate new ones  with  a button event i am using.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that uses div instead of table, in case someone needs this some day. Displays five numbers (of one or two digits) evenly spaced inside a div that has a fixed width.

The CSS

```
.container
{
    display:flex;
    justify-content:space-between;
    width: 125px;
    font-size:25px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
.item
{
    display:inline;
}
```

The javascript:

```
var arr = new Array(5);
var i = 0, j, n;
var OK = true;
var printThis = " "; 
var table = "<div class='container'>"; 
while (i < arr.length) {
    n = Math.floor((Math.random() * 35) + 1);
    for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        if (arr[j] == n) {
            OK = false;
        }
    }
     if (OK) {
        arr[i] = n;
        table += "<div class='item'>" + arr[i] + "</div>"; 
        i++;
    }
    OK = true;
}
table += "</div>";
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = table;
```

The HTML:

```
<div style='border:1px solid black;display:inline-block' id='demo'></div>
```